# Seems nil CAN be coerced to a float?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application I'm seeing the following exception:
TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Float

I'm iterating through a hash and running the following:

```
v[:score] = (1 / v[:distance].to_f) * v[:weight]
```

However, when I try to debug at the rails console, I don't get an exception. In fact, if I run:

```
nil.to_f
```

I get 0. So at the console running my line above yields Infinity since I'm dividing by zero.

So my question is, it seems that nil CAN be coerced to a float, so why am I getting an exception in my application?

Thanks!

Comment: You're probably asking the wrong question.  The right question to ask would be either "why is this behavior different," or "how can I get the coercion if I really want it?"

Comment: The coercion method is `to_float`, not `to_f`. `to_f` is the conversion method. `nil` doesn't (and shouldn't) respond to `to_float`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error can occur :

```
arup@linux-wzza:~> pry
[1] pry(main)> (1/2.0) * nil
TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Float
from (pry):1:in `*'
[2] pry(main)>
```

In your app I am sure `v[:weight]` is giving `nil`. Problem is not from `v[:distance]`, as you have handled it `v[:distance].to_f`. Check *twice*, I am *damn sure*, `v[:weight]` is `nil` in any situation.

Comment: Cool. Yes looks like that was the problem. Thanks!